# Validating Product Idea with quants

Tags: validation

I once read that if you validate your product with potential users, seven out of eight people you ask should find the product useful. I don't remember who originally said that. Can somebody help me with the author?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was

##### Paul Graham, co-founder of YC.

You should be able to find it in one of his essays here– https://paulgraham.com/articles.html. I, myself don't really vouch for the 7/8 (87.5%) quants that he mentions per se though.

Comment: I didn't know about this, but I agree with you, that figure is ridiculous